# Cannot read property 'scrollRequest' of undefined even though it should be

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to build some kind of smooth scroll - anyways `this.scroller.scrollRequest` is a static value that is predefined inside of my class:

```
scroller = {
   target: null,
   ease: 0.05,
   endY: 0,
   y: 0,
   resizeRequest: 1,
   scrollRequest: 0,
};
```

This value is being changed on scroll, it seems that on scroll `scrollRequest` is undefined. How so?

> Cannot read property 'scrollRequest' of undefined

That's where it's being called:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.fetchProjects();

   this.scroller.target = document.querySelector(".ch--scrollable-container");
   window.focus();

   window.addEventListener("resize", this.onResize());
   document.addEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll);
}

onScroll() {
   this.scroller.scrollRequest++; <-- causing the error
   if (!this.requestId) {
       this.requestId = requestAnimationFrame(this.updateScroller.bind(this));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` can't access to the value. use arrow functions like this:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    // ...
}

onScroll = () => {
    // ...
}
```